# Mysql 5.0.91 BIGINT column value comparison with '1'

Tags: mysql

Wondering what's wrong with comparing BIGINT column values with '1'. Exactly, why this isn't producing any results:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = '1'`

while this works just fine (i.e. returns non-empty result).

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = 1`

Thanks

Comment: What is the datatype of `col`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are comparing an integer, you do not need quotes around it.

This appears to possibly be an unresolved bug.

See [MySQL Bugs](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=9088)

Comment: it's big int, and I use it for consistency... unfortunately, it doesn't work :)

Comment: same response, when using any integer, bigint, you do not need quotes around the value

Comment: you don't **need** quotes, but if you do use them, it should still work

Comment: @Peter I just found that myself, it looks as if it is an unresolved bug

Comment: Found this bug there and it's marked as closed. Apparently it was removed in this commit http://lists.mysql.com/commits/3311

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use quotes in comparing with `Int` or `BigInt`.

But I am getting result even I am comparing with quotes.

[See this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3289e/1)

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this :) but it's probably a different server version. Love the fiddle though ;)