# How to properly compare BigInt Column in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, mysql-5.7

I took a lok at [Mysql 5.0.91 BIGINT column value comparison with '1'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110976/mysql-5-0-91-bigint-column-value-comparison-with-1) to check if there is some best practices for BigInt but found nothing.

I have a column that is BigInt(20) and my query has a WHERE clause that compares the column of type BigInt IN ().  This has a major impact on the performance.  Althought I have an index for that when I don't use this IN condition the query performance increases a lot.

So what is the best way to do that comparison I need?  IN () is a good practice or there is a best approach?

Table Description (Obfuscated for security reasons)

```
Field,Type,Null,Key,Default,Extra
id,bigint(20),NO,PRI,NULL,auto_increment
status,varchar(64),NO,,NULL,
dono_id,bigint(20),YES,,NULL,
dono_tipo,varchar(64),YES,MUL,NULL,
MyBigIntField,bigint(20),YES,MUL,NULL
```

QUERY

```
explain select
  DISTINCT(MyBigIntField)
FROM
  MyTable
WHERE
  MyBigIntField IN ('16', '49', '58', '155', '226')
  AND NOT (status = 'Failure')
  AND dono_id <> 1106
  and dono_tipo = 'Purchase';
```

Execution Plan

```
EXPLAIN
"{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "23.21"
    },
    "duplicates_removal": {
      "using_filesort": false,
      "table": {
        "table_name": "MyTable",
        "access_type": "range",
        "possible_keys": [
          "idx_MyTable_owner",
          "IDX_MyTable_PI"
        ],
        "key": "IDX_MyTable_PI",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "MyBigIntField"
        ],
        "key_length": "9",
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 13,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 5,
        "filtered": "45.00",
        "index_condition": "(`MyDatabase`.`MyTable`.`MyBigIntField` in (16,49,58,155,226))",
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "22.04",
          "eval_cost": "1.17",
          "prefix_cost": "23.21",
          "data_read_per_join": "231K"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "id",
          "status",
          "dono_id",
          "dono_tipo",
          "MyBigIntField"
        ],
        "attached_condition": "((`MyDatabase`.`MyTable`.`status` <> 'Failure') and (`MyDatabase`.`MyTable`.`dono_id` <> 1106) and (`MyDatabase`.`MyTable`.`dono_tipo` = 'Purchase'))"
      }
    }
  }
}"
```

Comment: In clause are a lot of or clauses only as shortcut, so indexes will not help. further myslq 5.0 is way out of old and deprecated, don' tyou think a switch to somewhat more actual will be better

Comment: If you have performance issues please post the query you are using, table description  and execution plan

Comment: @ErgestBasha I edited the post to add the info u required.  Please take a look if u can.

Comment: The question @nbk is about Query Optimization for MySQL 5.7 not 5.0.  Suggest to update the Database version when the question is about query is not constructive.  DB update is not simple and requires lot of effort on regression tests on all systems that uses this DB and sometimes they are proprietary old systems that might not offer support for new versions.

Again, lets stick with the idea of Query please.  Thank you.

Comment: @DanielFerreiraCastro Quering in 5ß or 5.7 follow the same rules, the where clause columns ahve  to be in a combined Index, as the granularity is a major issue, you need to test the order of columns in the index.

Comment: So @nbk if I create a composite index containing  MyBigIntField, statu, dono_id, dono_tipo this would have a major improvment on that query execution.  IS that it?  Like CREATE INDEX INDEX_NAME ON TABLE_NAME ( MyBigIntField, statu, dono_id, dono_tipo);  Taking into consideration the order of the columns to create a better index.

Comment: @DanielFerreiraCastro yes create the composite index like the order of the column used in the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
myBigInt = 1   -- fine
myBigInt = "1"   -- also good
myBigInt = (1)   -- optimizer treats this as the same

myBigInt = (1,2)  -- Now the query may run a lot slower
myBigInt = ('1', '2')  -- Same as without quotes
```

That is, `IN` with more than one value may or may not be done an efficient way.  We need to see the rest of the query in order to discuss that might happen.

Note that many APIs quote numbers while 'binding' values.  As pointed out above, that does not hurt performance.

```
WHERE
  MyBigIntField IN ('16', '49', '58', '155', '226')
  AND NOT (status = 'Failure')
  AND dono_id <> 1106
  and dono_tipo = 'Purchase';
```

Add a 'composite' index.  Start with any `=` tested columns, then `IN` and/or one of the other columns.  So , for *that* `WHERE`:

```
INDEX(dono_tipo, MyBigIntField)
```

`NOT`, `<>`, `>`, `BETWEEN` are harder to optimize.

If there are *only* two `status` values, then

```
 ... AND status = 'success' ...

INDEX(dono_tipo, status, MyBigIntField)
```

(There may be other optimizations that you show up if the example were not too obfuscated.)

Here's a similar case, with a different analysis:

```
WHERE
  MyBigIntField IN ('16', '49', '58', '155', '226')
  AND foo > 5
  and dono_tipo = 'Purchase';
```

In this case, I recommend

```
INDEX(dono_tipo,   -- first, because of "="
      MyBigIntField,  -- next because of IN
      foo)   -- range, which will be useful if IN has only one value
```

You seem to have `MyBigIntField` `NULLable`; perhaps it should be `NOT NULL`?  (This does not impact what I have said above.)